# How to exclude node_modules folder from publish artifact in VSTS

Tags: npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I currently have a build definition in place to build my project and publish my files for release. My project relies on a bit of NPM to do some automation using Gulp.js. I dont need it for anything else once my gulp-tasks have run.

When I get to my `publish artifacts` step, it publishes all of the files in the `node_modules` directory even though I don't even have them in my repo. I was wondering if there was a way to exclude them from within the contents section or if anyone else has a better idea?

Here is my Publish Artifacts settings:
[image]

In the Contents section, I also tried:

```
**\*
!**\node_modules\*
```

I am pretty new with the Build & Release process and I am unsure what other information might be needed to help debug this issue. So please comment and I can include information as needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since **Copy and Publish Build Artifacts task** is deprecated now, you’d better use **Copy Files task** and **Publish Build Artifacts task** instead. And these two tasks can help you exclude `node_modules` folder from publishing to server. Detail settings as below:

#### Copy Files task

Source Folder: `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)`

Contents:

```
**\**
!**\node_modules\**
```

Target Folder: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

[image]

#### Publish Build Artifacts task

Publish Build Artifacts task: `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`

Artifact Name: `drop`

[image]

Comment: That did it for me! Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't forget to use '/' instead of '\' on Linux.